Are there alternatives to having an idle thread waiting for user input, in gaming?
I've coded a very basic Snake game, and as far as input/output goes, I've taken the following approach:

I create an MVar to store the most recent keypress;
I use withAsync to spawn two threads, both of which I pass that MVar to;

One thread uses tryTakeMVar to check if any key was pressed, and then updates the game state according to the pressed key if any (I mean, it updates the state even if no key was pressed)
The other thread just blocks on getChar and, when a key is ever pressed, it uses putMVar to store it, for the former thread to pick it up.



Now, surely snake is not a game where you stay there without pressing keys for long, but still, given the little amount of processing that thead 2 does, I understand it is blocked on getChar 99% of the time, to say the least.
That doesn't look like a good usage of a thread, so can I do anything better?
I do think there must be some fundamental flaw about my understanding of multithreading, because I can't help but thinking that something must be idle waiting for an input, otherwise who's gonna pick that up? And what could that thing be, if not a thread?

I can think of a single thread approach where one uses an hypothetical timeout version of getChar and just use that as part of the loop that updates the game state, but it doesn't sound like an approach that scales to more serious games.

See also How can I poll files, sockets or handles to become readable/writable in Haskell?. Short summary: my personal view is that having a thread that simply blocks waiting for input is the cleanest design, but things like hIsReadable and hGetBufNonBlocking do exist.

Note that, unlike in some other languages, threads in Haskell are generally very cheap.  You don't generally have to worry about "good usage of a thread" in the same way.

Haskell threads in general do not correspond to OS threads, but are much cheaper. For instance, if you spawn two Haskell threads, one waiting for keyboard input, and another one waiting for network data, these might be run on a single OS thread using select/poll or other similar demultiplexing OS system calls. This is automatically done by the GHC runtime. Rolling your own single-Haskell-thread solution could make things less efficient. I think you can force the GHC RTS to use only a single OS thread passing the right flags if you want to (but do you really need that?).

@chi, I'm not sure if you mean I'm "spawning two Haskell thread" or I am "rolling my own single-Haskell-thread solution".

If you are using forkIO you are spawning multiple Haskell threads.

@chi, doesn't withAsync spawn a thread usng forkIO?

Yes, it looks like it's using a slight variant of forkIO, but that's not important -- it's still creating a Haskell thread.

@chi, ok, so whether I'm using withAsync or forkIO, I'm creating a "Haskell thread", understood. What I don't understand is the two terms compared via "less efficient" in your original comment. Is it my approach less efficient than what, or what less efficient than my approach? Or what?

The only alternative I can see would be avoiding forkIO, forkOS,withAsync,... and similar functions and do all the demultiplexing using the lower level select/poll. This would be a single loop of the form (pseudocode) e <- waitForAnyEvent [source1, source2, ....] ; handle e ; loop. It's arguably more complex to code (although some things become easier) with no obvious performance benefit over Haskell threads.

Your approach is correct. This is how all video games (actually all interactive applications) do it.
In fact both of your threads mainly waiting, unless your snake is supersonic :) and running at maximum speed.

One thread wait for user input
One thread process game logic and wait for next tick
Usually there is another thread that renders game state to the screen. In your case you probably just update video buffer, so you don't need that.

